# AutoMapper define mapping level

Tags: c#, automapper

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Baz { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

When I map the class above, is there any way to define how deep I want automapper to map objects? Some pseudo code of what I'm after:

```
var mapped = Mapper.Map<FooDTO>(foo, opt => { levels: 0 });
// result = { Baz: "" }

var mapped = Mapper.Map<FooDTO>(foo, opt => { levels: 1 });
// result = { Baz: "", Bars: [{ Blah: "" }] }

 var mapped = Mapper.Map<FooDTO>(foo, opt => { levels: 2 });
// result = { Baz: "", Bars: [{ Blah: "", Buzz: [{ Baz: "" }] }] }

// etc...
```

I'm currently using automapper 3.3 due to a nuget dependency.

Comment: There is no way to set levels in automapper even in latest version. Because You only deal with 1 level of hierarchy at a time.  In your case you need 2 mapper configurations. One for `Foo` and second for `Bar`. You can use `opt.Ignore()` in your mapper configuration for any property which you do not want to map . Automapper does automatically map if the names of the objects are same or matching. I think in your case object names are different and you need configuration for each object.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by providing a value at runtime as was answered in question: [How to ignore a property based on a runtime condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859214/how-to-ignore-a-property-based-on-a-runtime-condition).

**Configuration:**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDTO>().ForMember(e => e.Bars,
    o => o.Condition(c => !c.Options.Items.ContainsKey("IgnoreBars")));
```

**Usage:**

```
Mapper.Map<FooDTO>(foo, opts => { opts.Items["IgnoreBars"] = true; });
```

Same configuration approach you can apply for all your nested objects that you call levels.

If you want to achieve same behavior for your DB Entities you can use `ExplicitExpansion` approach as described in this answer: [Is it possible to tell automapper to ignore mapping at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751531/is-it-possible-to-tell-automapper-to-ignore-mapping-at-runtime).

**Configuration:**

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooDTO>()
    .ForMember(e => e.Bars, o => o.ExplicitExpansion());
```

**Usage:**

```
dbContext.Foos.Project().To<FooDTO>(membersToExpand: d => d.Bars);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define map specific `MaxDepth` like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().MaxDepth(1);
```

More info:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki